# How to remove image resizing in Prestashop?

Tags: image, prestashop

When uploading an image in Prestashop, my image is resized accordingly to settings. Can I remove the resize treatment and use native uploaded images in my website?

Answer (score 0):

Images are resized in different size needed for different uses in Prestashop, so disabled fully this feature is not an good idea.

but to get the original image, you need to change path image in your file.tpl

```
https://example.com/img/p/{$id_product}/{$name_product}.jpg
```